# python autohotkey dll script not launching

Tags: python, dll, autohotkey

I had a few errors in my code from before. I've run it through a python validator and it doesn't throw an error but it doesn't launch in the autohotkey or python program.  I know I need to put in the wrapper ctypes but not sure where.  Could it be this missing python module that keeps it from running? 
 Here is the code currently:

```
ahk = cdll.AutoHotkey
parser = ahk
ahk.key_press(ahk.key_press("^+c", print, ahk.key_press("f", "{enter}")))
ahk.key_press("^+z", print, ahk.key_press("u", "{enter}"))
ahk.key_press(ahk.key_press("^+x", print, ahk.key_press("m", "{enter}")))
cmp_func = CMPFUNC(py_cmp_func)fx = create_string_buffer(str(cast(cmp_func, c_void_p).value))
ahk.ahkdll(pyclient, "", fx)
ahk.addScript(script)
```

Any ideas why it isn't launching? Thanks for your help.

Comment: i can not see why it does not work but if you want to simple **send any text** or **send any keystrokes Macros** with a **single line of code**, then you can use package [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) `import pyautogui `-`pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')` this is a good alternative compared with autohotkey.dll

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Yeah that's a good way to go too.  I'm looking to go through pyahk/autohotkey dll so I can run it directly through my work computer and not python terminal.  Is there a way I could do that through pyautogui without running through the python terminal?

Comment: if you want to run it without the python terminal, you can use instead of `.py` extension, you can then use `.pyw` extension - or if you want to use onscreen buttons on the Windows Desktop you can use this Tool [AutopythonLauncher](http://autopythonclipboardlauncher.com/) - These Buttons can Execute any python scripts & can Execute in any applications. **(without loosing the focus of the Windows)**